# AWS Base Image Multiple Lambdas (dockerfile)

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile, aws-cdk

this is my dockerfile. I have a directory of different lambdas and I need to be able to run one of them based off of a variable or similar. Right now it is hardcoded to run lambda1.handler, but what if I want it to run lambda2.handler ... lambda-n.handler?

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY lambda/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/"

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "lambda1.handler" ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS CKD, you can overwrite it within `fromImageAsset`:

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { Runtime } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import {aws_lambda as lambda } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as path from 'path';

export class CdkLambdaPythonStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, 'AssetFunction_1', {
      code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(
        path.join(__dirname, '../path_to_dockerfile'),
        {
          cmd : ["lambda1.handler"]
        }
      )
    });
    }
}
```